# Use different SSH keys on same PC and same repo?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I am trying to do a setup where I can do commits/pushes from one single machine using different SSH keys. I have seen variations of this question but the answers revolve around having repositories `A` and `B` with a and b users for both accounts, and only ever using `a@A` for the first repo and `b@B` for the second. I have repo A which needs to be able to be commited/pushed to by users a, b, c, and d, and a way to switch between ssh keys without much hassle.

I have tried ssh -i {key file path} to no avail, is there any other way to do this without having to introduce credentials every time a different user wants to commit?

Comment: ssh doesn't matter for committing?

Comment: Wait, it doesn't? I haven't tried in bitbucket, but I remember in github when you commit with your SSH using other person's username, the commit doesn't link it to their actual username.

Comment: bitbucket and github are not related to the commits. ssh is only for fetching/pushing to a remote. the info contained in git commits is controlled by the git config settings.

Comment: So a user could commit and push changes only knowing another user's name and email using whatever SSH keys grant acces to push?

Comment: If the ssh user has permission to push, yes. git does not authenticate users.

Comment: Ok thanks! that saved up a morning of time haha.

Comment: this will help you :https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssh-keys-ae6688f76570#54ba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commit username is only related to `git config user.name`/`user.email` values, and has nothing to do with authentication.

Authentication only matters when pushing to /cloning from a remote repository, where the remote repository hosting service (GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket...) would require to know who you are, in order to make sure you have the *right* to push or clone.

I often have multiple users all logged on the same technical service account, and having to contribute a repository on that server.
I use a Git wrapper (my own: [`VonC/gitw`](https://github.com/VonC/gitw)) in order to force the user to declare who they are at the first git command.
That will [set `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME/EMAIL` and `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME/EMAIL`](https://github.com/VonC/gitw/blob/86ddc4ad4c50c4e86be26476ab054a5c5ee3bd8e/gitw.sh#L89-L92=), based on `.gituser` custom file (which registers their email for a given name)

That way, user `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` always make commit with their own user name/email, even though they are all logged as "technical-account".